# Python projects depending on one another in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a workspace in VSCode with some Python projects which depend on one another. I'd like to test changes on some projects at the same time. Is it possible to configure VSCode (maybe with a plugin) in order to do so?

Comment: maybe you can try these:
you may be able to use the `pythonpath` setting in pytest for testing directly. 
In vscode, try https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_settings

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want, sorry ^^ What do you mean by "test changes on some projects at the same time" ? If project A depends on B, then editing B will change the behavior of A, I don't get the stuff about a configuration or plugin you are looking for ?

Comment: is https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need to set up a workspace in VS Code that includes all
   of your Python projects. You can do this by going to `File -> Add Folder to Workspace...` and adding each of your Python project
   folders to the workspace.
2. Then you have to set python interpreter for Python project.
3. VS Code supports running unit tests via the Python Test Explorer extension. Install it from the VS Code marketplace. Once installed, you can discover and run your tests directly from the Test Explorer pane. You can configure it to discover tests in all your projects.